# List range of numbers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of numbers in excel:

1
2
3
6
9
10
11
15
18

I would like a formula to list the ranges that are a difference of 1, so:
1-3
6
9-11
15
18

Can anyone please help me? 
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you clarify what you mean by * a difference of 1*? As written it's hard to understand what your question is.  What have you tried to accomplish this? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible with a basic formula.  However, I have also had this need before, and I wrote a worksheet function:

```
Public Function ConcatInts(target As Range) As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n0 As Long
    Dim n1 As Long
    Dim n2 As Long
    Dim flag As Boolean
    n0 = 0
    n1 = target.Cells(1).Value
    n2 = n1
    flag = False
    For i = 2 To target.Cells.Count
        If IsNumeric(target.Cells(i).Value) Then
            n2 = target.Cells(i).Value
            If n2 = n1 + 1 Then
                If Not flag Then
                    n0 = n1
                    s = s & n1 & "-"
                    flag = True
                End If
            ElseIf n2 <> n1 Then
                If n1 = n0 + 1 And right(s, 1) = "-" Then
                    s = left(s, Len(s) - 1) & " "
                End If
                s = s & n1 & " "
                flag = False
            End If
            n1 = n2
        End If
    Next
    If n1 = n0 + 1 And right(s, 1) = "-" Then
        s = left(s, Len(s) - 1) & " "
    End If
    s = s & n1
    ConcatInts = s
End Function
```

To use this, you have to open up the VBA editor by pressing ALT+F11.  Then right-click the workbook from the navigation pane and select Insert->Module:

[image]

Then just copy-paste the code into the module.

Now you can call it as you would a regular function:

```
=ConcatInts(A1:I1)
```

Note that this function skips over cells containing text, automatically converts floating-point numbers to integers, and discards duplicates. It also requires that your numbers be sorted.

Don't forget to save your workbook as a macro-enabled workbook (XLSM).